# This is not permitted when the subquery follows >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server

I have my Query like this

```
    CREATE  TRIGGER  check_shippeddate_tr
    ON  Orders
    FOR UPDATE
    AS
    IF      ((SELECT ShippedDate    FROM inserted) > (SELECT RequiredDate FROM Orders) )
                BEGIN
                                PRINT   'Order must be shipped before required date'
                                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                END
                GO
```

Yet, when i try to UPDATE the table use this code

```
    UPDATE Orders
    SET ShippedDate = '1994-04-03'
    WHERE   OrderID = 11051
    AND     CustomerID = 'LAMAI'
    AND     EmployeeID = 7
```

It should prevent the update and print the message because ShippedDate is after the RequiredDate. However i got this error"**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**" How do I fix it?

Comment: The error message is straightforward: `SELECT foo FROM bar` returns a **table** of results rather than a single scalar value. Use an aggregate (e.g. `MAX`), add a `WHERE` condition to restrict it to 1 result, or use `SELECT TOP 1`.

Comment: Or perhaps you intended `SELECT RequiredDate FROM inserted` if it was intended to be a validation on the ShippedDate > RequiredDate of the inserted item.

Comment: @Dai  I tried like this ((SELECT TOP 1 ShippedDate FROM inserted) > (SELECT TOP 1 RequiredDate FROM Orders) ) and when I try to update it. It always active the trigger and print the message. How do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like .....

Assuming OrderID is a Primary Key column

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  check_shippeddate_tr
ON  Orders
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i 
           inner join Orders o ON i.OrderID = o.OrderID
           WHERE  i.ShippedDate > O.RequiredDate)
        BEGIN
                        PRINT   'Order must be shipped before required date'
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

create a check constraint on your table

```
ALTER TABLE Orders 
ADD CHECK (ShippedDate < RequiredDate)
```